# Complete Waterproof Service Panel AWG 1 Splice

Tags: connectors

We need to splice or extend existing AWG 1 main service panel wires and the splice would be left open to rain. What kind of connectors that would create watertight waterproof splice?

I have this (but putting tape all over it would not create waterproof splice because water can leak in:

[image]

Comment: Are you merely making an *electrical* splice, or does this involve extending the *messenger* (the bare wire the other wires are twisted around) as well?

Comment: It's just stranded wires without bare core wire. I just want to extend AWG 1 by about 3 meters so any connections will do as long as it can splice them together but the connectors will be exposed to rain. So need watertight connector.. any ideas?

Comment: Any chance of getting a picture of this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I'd use a Burndy UGSKIT250

For this sort of outdoor/exposed-splice application (as you would find when splicing a triplex or quadruplex overhead feeder or service cable to riser wires in a mast), I would use a Burndy UGSKIT250 for the individual wire splices.  This kit consists of a bare (uninsulated) mechnical splice suitable for 1AWG-250kcmil wire, either copper or aluminum, and a length of heavy wall heat shrink tubing to be shrunk over the top of the splice for waterproofing.  It is UL listed for use outdoors (and even in direct burial applications), and does not require any sort of junction box.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're the power company I don't think you can do that. You'd have to have a water tight/weatherproof junction box and then use split bolt connectors, if they're still allowed. In my experience the  cable is usually replaced.

ThreePhaseEel has a way to do this.

Comment: The cables are 30 meters long and impossible to replace. Just need 3 additional meters to add to it. So use split bolt connectors inside waterproof junction? Is there any enclosure where the sole purpose is just to connect two wires together. Imagine breakers but without the internal parts, just the terminals.

Comment: There are splice kits made for this sort of work (usually either a compression or a mechanical splice, with heat shrink tubing over the top)

Comment: We had them at the power company but I didn't think they were for commercial use. Didn't think inspectors approved them...

Comment: @JACK -- the Burndy UGSKIT family are UL/CSA listed...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Wow!. "Just need 3 additional meters to add to it." It was late and I thought the OP wanted to add three meters (electric) to the existing wires.... wondered why the power company wasn't doing this... would that be meters or yards..

Answer (score 1):

Exterior wires (in **wet** locations, which may well be submerged at least some of the time) are **quite commonly spliced** - it's just a matter of the proper materials; but this is perhaps a place where both having the proper materials **and** having **experience** employing them suggest a pro might be worth their fee.

"Self-fusing" rubber splicing tape is one common material employed. It has the advantage of fitting whatever connector you use easily, but you do need to apply it competently to get a good seal.

Large scale heat shrink tubing may well be an option (I certainly have heat-shrink covered splices in my well connecting the well pump 12 AWG wires which are under 200 feet of water most of the time) but what I first found when looking for 1 AWG suited shrink tubing were "cold-shrink" products claiming a moisture-proof seal. Supplied stretched on a cardboard tube. "*Removal of the core (unwinding) after positioning the splice allows the product to shrink into position forming a moisture-tight seal.*"